# Getting full coverage for test class for boolean value?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, callout, failing-tests

This UserMigrationRoute class is migrating Community profile users to Partner profile and saving their username Password in userMigration object. I have really hard time writing test classes. I have written Test class which I am getting **65 percent** coverage!
This is main class where from **line no. 43-77** is not covered

```
public class UserMigrationRoute extends BaseRoute{
public override Object doPost() {
    List<String> allowhosts=Label.Host_Name.split(',');
    Map<String,object> maprespone=new  Map<String,object>();
    system.debug('Hi');
    if(String.isNotBlank(request.headers.get('Host')) && String.isNotBlank(request.headers.get('Host')) && !allowhosts.contains(request.headers.get('Host'))){
        setResponseMessage('Invalid Host Header',ConstantsUtils.ERROR_CODE);   
        return null;  
    }
    if(this.request.headers.get('Content-Type')!=null && this.request.headers.get('Content-Type').substringAfter('/').equalsIgnoreCase('xml')){
        setResponseMessage('Request in '+request.headers.get('Content-Type').substringAfter('/')+' format. Please provide request in json format.',ConstantsUtils.ERROR_CODE);
        return null;
    }
    map<String,object> data=this.getBodyJSON();
    string id=(string)data.get('userId');
    Map<String,String> mapofPartnerRecordType=new Map<String,String>();
    List<User> objUser;
    try{
        objUser=[SELECT Id,Profile.NAME,IsActive ,userName,AccountId,Account.IsPartner,IsPortalEnabled  FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE and AccountId!=null and id=:id];
        if(objUser==null ||  objUser.size()==0){
            setResponseMessage('Invalid uesrId, Please provide community user id',ConstantsUtils.ERROR_CODE); 
            return null;
        } 
        List<Account> lstAccount=new List<Account>();
        if(!objUser[0].Account.IsPartner){
            Account account=new Account();
            account.Id=objUser[0].AccountId;
            account.IsPartner=true;
            lstAccount.add(account);
           // update lstAccount;  //commented by shabnoor for testing
        }
        
        if(mapOfCustomerAndPartner.containsKey(objUser[0].profile.Name)){
            String partnerProfile=mapOfCustomerAndPartner.get(objUser[0].profile.Name);
            objUser[0].ProfileId=[Select Id , Name from profile where Name= :partnerProfile].Id;
        }
        
        update objUser[0];
        
        Boolean isSUccess=createUserMigration('',objUser[0],'');
        if(isSUccess){
            maprespone.put('statuscode',1);
            maprespone.put('statusmessage','user migration successfully done'); 
            return maprespone;
        }
        maprespone.put('statuscode',0);
        maprespone.put('statusmessage','user migration failed');
        return maprespone;
        
    }
    catch(DMLException ex){
        
        if(ex.getDmlType(0)==StatusCode.DUPLICATE_USERNAME){
            String charString = '!@#$%^&*()nopqrstuvwABCDPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijkEFGHIJKLMNOlmxyz';
            String randomNew = '';
            while (randomNew .length() < 8){
                Integer changeInt = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), charString.length());
                randomNew += charString.substring(changeInt , changeInt +1);
            }
            Boolean isSUccess=createUserMigration(objUser[0].userName.replace('@',DateTime.now().millisecond() +'@'),objUser[0],randomNew);
            if(isSUccess){
                system.setPassword(objUser[0].Id, randomNew);
                maprespone.put('statuscode',1);
                maprespone.put('statusmessage','user migration successfully done'); 
                return maprespone;
            }
            maprespone.put('statuscode',0);
            maprespone.put('statusmessage',ex.getMessage());
            return maprespone;
        }
        maprespone.put('statuscode',0);
        maprespone.put('statusmessage',ex.getMessage());
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        maprespone.put('statuscode',0);
        maprespone.put('statusmessage',ex.getMessage());
        return maprespone;
    }
    return maprespone;
}

public void setResponseMessage(String strMessge,String strCode){
    response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf( '[{"message":' + strMessge + ',"errorCode":'+ strCode + '}]' );
    response.statusCode = 400;
    
}

public Boolean  createUserMigration(String Newusername,User objUser,String tempPassword){
    try{
        UserMigration__c UserMigration=new UserMigration__c();
       // UserMigration.Newusername__c=objUser.userName;
        if(String.isNotBlank(Newusername)){
            UserMigration.Newusername__c=Newusername;
        }
        UserMigration.OlduserName__c=objUser.userName;
        UserMigration.User__c=objUser.id;
        if(String.isNotBlank(tempPassword)){
            UserMigration.tempPassword__c= tempPassword; 
        }
        insert UserMigration;
        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
    }
    
}

public map<String,String> mapOfCustomerAndPartner=new Map<String,String>{
    'Customer Community - Admin'=>'Partner Community - Admin',
        'Customer Community - Agent'=>'Partner Community - Agent',
        'Customer Community - Agent + Admin'=>'Partner Community - Agent + Admin',
        'Customer Community - Auth + Admin'=>'Partner Community - Auth + Admin',
        'Customer Community - Auth + Admin + Agent'=>'Partner Community - Auth + Admin + Agent',
        'Customer Community - Auth + Agent'=>'Partner Community - Auth + Agent',
        'Customer Community - Auth Officer'=>'Partner Community - Auth Officer',
        'Customer Community - Customer Direct User'=>'Partner Community - Customer Direct User',
        'Customer Community - Owner'=>'Partner Community - Owner',           
        'Customer Community Plus User'=>'Partner Community - Admin',
        'Customer Direct Guest'=>'Partner Direct Guest'
        };
            
            
            
            }
```

And this is test class I have written-

```
@isTest
public with sharing class UserMigrationRouteTest {      
    
    @testSetup
    static void setup() {
        Broker_App_Settings__c BAS = new Broker_App_Settings__c(
            General_Partner_User_Id__c = '0054H0000067b6o',
            ApiToken__c = '6e9bece1914809fb8493146417e722f6',
            IVector__c = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF',
            Key__c = 'x/A%D*G-KaPdSgVkYp3s6v9y&B&E(H+M',
            General_Partner_User_Name__c = 'qaqqqqqqqqqqqqqq.com'
        );
        insert BAS;
        
        TestDataSetup.createIntegrationCustomSettingsData();
        TestDataSetup.createTriggerSettingsData();
        TestDataSetup.createAppSettingsData();
        Account partnerAccount = TestDataSetup.createAgencyAccount();
        insert partnerAccount;
        
        Contact objAgencyContact = TestDataSetup.createAgentContact(
            partnerAccount.Id
        );
        objAgencyContact.RERA_Card_No__c = '123456';
        objAgencyContact.Sys_Agent_Representative__c = true;
        insert objAgencyContact;
        
        Profile portalProfile = [
            SELECT Id
            FROM Profile
            WHERE Name = 'Sales Partner Community User'
            LIMIT 1
        ];
        
        User objPartnerUser = new User(
            Username = System.now().millisecond() + 'test999@test.com',
            ContactId = objAgencyContact.Id,
            ProfileId = portalProfile.Id,
            Alias = 'pTst',
            Email = 'testingisgoingon999@test.com',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LastName = 'Con',
            CommunityNickname = 'test999',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        );
        Database.insert(objPartnerUser);
    }

    
    static testMethod void verifyContentType() {
        User objPartnerUser = [
            SELECT Id, Username
            FROM User
            WHERE email = 'testingisgoingon999@test.com'
        ];
        System.runAs(objPartnerUser) {
            String requestURI = '/userprofileupdate/';
            String RESOURCE_PATH = '/services/apexrest' + requestURI;
            map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
            headers.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            headers.put('Host', 'www.gmail1.com');
            Broker_App_Settings__c BAS = Broker_App_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
            headers.put('apikey', BAS.ApiToken__c);
            Map<String, String> requestData = new Map<string, string>();
            String JsonRecord = Json.serialize(requestData);
            setRestCall(RESOURCE_PATH, requestURI, 'POST', headers, null, JsonRecord);
            try {
                RestResponse resp = RestContext.Response;
                UserMigrationResource.handlePost();
                resp = RestContext.Response;
            } catch (exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    
    static testMethod void createMigrationUserNegative(){

        List<User> objUser = [SELECT Id,Profile.NAME,IsActive ,userName,AccountId,Account.IsPartner,IsPortalEnabled  FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE and AccountId!=null];

        UserMigrationRoute mem = new UserMigrationRoute();
        Boolean isSUccess  = mem.createUserMigration('newusername123',objUser[0],'newpassword1234');
        System.assertEquals(false,isSUccess, 'Result');
    }
        static testMethod void createMigrationPositive(){

        List<User> objUser = [SELECT Id,Profile.NAME,IsActive ,userName,AccountId,Account.IsPartner,IsPortalEnabled  FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE and AccountId!=null];
        UserMigrationRoute mem = new UserMigrationRoute();
        Boolean isSUccess = mem.createUsermigration('',objUser[0],'');
        System.assertEquals(true,isSUccess,'result');
    
    }
    
    static testMethod void verifydoPost() {

        User objPartnerUser = [
            SELECT Id, Username
            FROM User
            WHERE email = 'testingisgoingon999@test.com'
        ];
        System.runAs(objPartnerUser) {
            CaseTriggerHandler.TriggerDisabled = true;
            String requestURI = '///userprofileupdate/';
            String RESOURCE_PATH = '/services/apexrest' + requestURI;
            map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
            Broker_App_Settings__c BAS = Broker_App_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
            headers.put('apikey', BAS.ApiToken__c);
            Map<String, String> requestData = new Map<string, string>();
            requestData.put('userId', '0053M000001YvnTQAS');
            String JsonRecord = Json.serialize(requestData);
            setRestCall(RESOURCE_PATH, requestURI, 'POST', headers, null, JsonRecord);
            
            try {
                RestResponse resp = RestContext.Response;
                UserMigrationResource.handlePost();
                resp = RestContext.Response;
                //System.assertEquals(1,resp.statusCode,'success'); //Assert with expected status code.
            } catch (exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void setRestCall(
        String resourcePath,
        String requestURI,
        String method,
        map<String, String> headers,
        map<String, String> paraMeters,
        String body
    ) {
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        req.requestURI = requestURI;
        req.resourcePath = resourcePath;
        req.httpMethod = method;
        
        if (String.isNotEmpty(body)) {
            req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf(body);
        }
        if (headers != null && headers.size() > 0) {
            req.headers.putAll(headers);
        }
        if (paraMeters != null && paraMeters.size() > 0) {
            req.params.putAll(paraMeters);
        }
        system.debug('test' + req);
        RestContext.Request = req;
        RestContext.Response = new RestResponse();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Note that the `testMethod` keyword is deprecated, and you should be using the `@isTest` annotation for your test methods instead (as well as for the overall class definition).

Comment: I will replace that.